# Using Handsontable-in-handsontable, how can I return values from one column only?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I'm attempting to use the "Handsontable" editor inside a Handsontable grid. I want the user to be able to select from a "dropdown" type menu, but one that shows multiple columns of related data(The user is selecting an ID number, and I want to be able to show the related Name and Age, for instance).
I have this working, but the user can click on /any/ cell in the popup editor, and it will return whatever is in that cell. On the "ID" cell it works great, but I can easily get a "Name" or "Age" returned when I only want values from the ID column.

Any ideas on how to force the return value to /only/ be from one column?

http://jsfiddle.net/sq9xs5a7/

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  function getCarData() {
    return [
      ["Nissan", 2013, "black", "black"],
      ["Nissan", 2014, "blue", "blue"],
      ["Chrysler", 2015, "yellow", "black"],
      ["Volvo", 2016, "white", "gray"]
    ];
  }

  var
    carData = getCarData(),
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    manufacturerData,
    colors,
    color,
    colorData = [],
    hot;

  manufacturerData = [
    {name: 'BMW', country: 'Germany', owner: 'Bayerische Motoren Werke AG'},
    {name: 'Chrysler', country: 'USA', owner: 'Chrysler Group LLC'},
    {name: 'Nissan', country: 'Japan', owner: 'Nissan Motor Company Ltd'},
    {name: 'Suzuki', country: 'Japan', owner: 'Suzuki Motor Corporation'},
    {name: 'Toyota', country: 'Japan', owner: 'Toyota Motor Corporation'},
    {name: 'Volvo', country: 'Sweden', owner: 'Zhejiang Geely Holding Group'}
  ];
  colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'gray', 'black', 'white'];

  while (color = colors.shift()) {
    colorData.push([
      [color]
    ]);
  }

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: carData,
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Year', 'Chassis color', 'Bumper color'],
    columns: [
      {
        type: 'handsontable',
        handsontable: {
          colHeaders: ['Marque', 'Country', 'Parent company'],
          data: manufacturerData
        }
      },
      {type: 'numeric'},
      {
        type: 'handsontable',
        handsontable: {
          colHeaders: false,
          data: colorData
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'handsontable',
        handsontable: {
          colHeaders: false,
          data: colorData
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  function bindDumpButton() {
      if (typeof Handsontable === "undefined") {
        return;
      }

      Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(document.body, 'click', function (e) {

        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

        if (element.nodeName == "BUTTON" && element.name == 'dump') {
          var name = element.getAttribute('data-dump');
          var instance = element.getAttribute('data-instance');
          var hot = window[instance];
          console.log('data of ' + name, hot.getData());
        }
      });
    }
  bindDumpButton();

});
```

This is a good example of what I'm doing(pulled from the HoT help). And here, it works exactly like I have it. When you click on the 'Car' field, you can select 'Germany', when I really only want values from the first column in there.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a getValue() method to the HOT-in-HOT like below...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

  function getCarData() {
    return [
      ["Nissan", 2013, "black", "black"],
      ["Nissan", 2014, "blue", "blue"],
      ["Chrysler", 2015, "yellow", "black"],
      ["Volvo", 2016, "white", "gray"]
    ];
  }

  var
    carData = getCarData(),
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    manufacturerData,
    colors,
    color,
    colorData = [],
    hot;

  manufacturerData = [
    {name: 'BMW', country: 'Germany', owner: 'Bayerische Motoren Werke AG'},
    {name: 'Chrysler', country: 'USA', owner: 'Chrysler Group LLC'},
    {name: 'Nissan', country: 'Japan', owner: 'Nissan Motor Company Ltd'},
    {name: 'Suzuki', country: 'Japan', owner: 'Suzuki Motor Corporation'},
    {name: 'Toyota', country: 'Japan', owner: 'Toyota Motor Corporation'},
    {name: 'Volvo', country: 'Sweden', owner: 'Zhejiang Geely Holding Group'}
  ];
  colors = ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'gray', 'black', 'white'];

  while (color = colors.shift()) {
    colorData.push([
      [color]
    ]);
  }

  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: carData,
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Year', 'Chassis color', 'Bumper color'],
    columns: [
      {
    type: 'handsontable',
    handsontable: {
      colHeaders: ['Marque', 'Country', 'Parent company'],
      data: manufacturerData,
      getValue: function() {
        var selection = this.getSelected();

        // Get always manufacture name of clicked row
        return this.getSourceDataAtRow(selection[0]).name;
      }
    }
      },
      {type: 'numeric'},
      {
    type: 'handsontable',
    handsontable: {
      colHeaders: false,
      data: colorData
    }
      },
      {
    type: 'handsontable',
    handsontable: {
      colHeaders: false,
      data: colorData
    }
      }
    ],

  });

});
```